# How to realize the following condition in JavaScript:

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

For example, we have 9 pets in the room: cats, monkeys, and rabbits, how to check that correlation of cats to monkeys and rabbits, not bigger than 1:2 ?....truthy value would be 2 - 1, or 2 - 4 and falsy 1 - 3, or 2 - 5......Below is how I tried to solve this task :

```
function petsInRoom(cats, monkeys, rabbits) {
  // write code here
  if ((monkeys + rabbits) / cats != 2) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

Comment: If it's *not bigger than*, then it should be  `(monkeys + rabbits) / cats >= 2`, `!=` means **not equals to**

Comment: Consider writing the calculation before the if statement?

Comment: Hint: write the math  first, then write the code.

Comment: So any value of cats below monkeys + rabbits * 2 should return true?

Comment: "cats to monkeys and rabbits" yet "`(monkeys + rabbits) / cats`" - you are confusing us and yourself...  I know it's the same, but I would write in the same ORDER: "`cats / (monkeys + rabbits)`".

Comment: Thank you all guys, but I'm trying to input data in the function, and when we have a situation, when, we know only two variables for example petsInRoom(1, 2) ( I mean without rabbits) that returns false in any case, I guess I have to change the condition but I don't know how exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to return false if the number of cats divided by the number of (monkeys + rabbits) if superior to 1/2.

your should write something like this:

```
if (cats / (monkeys + rabbits) > 1/2) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

or you can write it in one line:

```
return !( cats / (monkeys + rabbits) > 1/2);
```

Edit:
something like this should work just fine:

```
function petsInRoom(cats, monkeys, rabbits) {
  if (rabbits === undefined) rabbits = 0;
  if ( cats / (monkeys + rabbits) > 0.5) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

Comment: The whole thing that I have to use ut in the function and if one of the variables is omitted like: petsInRoom(1, 2); it returns false

Comment: instead of omitting a variables, maybe you can just pass 0, and in this case you'll have to add more logic to your condition to prevent your code from dividing by 0.

Comment: I really appreciate that you are trying to help me, but I have conditions:

the room can accommodate no more than 8 animals + 1 (if it is a rabbit);
there must be at least one cat;
there can be no more than 2 monkeys and rabbits per one cat.

All that I have to check with my conditions in the function